# MySQL 5.7 Create Trigger Syntax Error?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin, mysql-5.7

I've been trying to create a simple `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on a database table (MySQL v 5.7 ) but I keep receiving a vague "#1064 ... syntax error" message which doesn't help resolve the issue.

Here's the SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER `CREATE_QUIZ_TRIG` BEFORE INSERT ON `quiz`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.ACTIVE = UPPER(NEW.ACTIVE);
    SET NEW.CREATED = NOW();
 END
/
```

All I'm trying to do is enforce a column to uppercase and then insert the current date & time into a timestamp column. I've been following the documentation from:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

and realise that for multi-statement expression I have to redefine the delimiter at the beginning of the trigger's creation but the same '#1064' error occurs.

This is made even more confusing because when I use phpmyadmin's interface for creating the same trigger it works fine - but won't when I export the generated SQL and try to create the trigger using that!?

Thanks for any help

Comment: but won't when I export the generated SQL and try to create the trigger using that!? - What does this mean?

Comment: PhpMyAdmin allows you to output the SQL used to create a table using it's GUI. When creating the table using this GUI, the trigger was created successfully - so I exported the SQL that it had generated and tried creating the table using that SQL instead of the GUI; this didn't work which I thought was peculiar.

Turns out that the issue was that PHPMyAdmin automatically sets the default delimiter of a trigger to `;` and this is why I was getting a syntax error when trying to create the trigger because of the semi-colons after the `SET ... ` command(s) - it thought that those were delimiters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realise that, by default, phpmyadmin adds a `;` delimiter which was breaking the `;` used to end a statement within the `BEGIN END` block.